# Validating multiple textboxes with multiple checks

Tags: vb.net, validation, textbox

I have multiple textboxes in a groupbox, and can successfully cycle through them all. However the checkNumbers sub fails to recognise blank/null entries, and also non-numeric characters. The correctValidation boolean should return true if all the criteria are met (no blanks/nulls, and must be a number between 1-20). Any thoughts on how to solve this would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub checkNumbers()

Try
            For Each txt As TextBox In Me.gbTechnical.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
                If txt.Text <> "" And IsNumeric(txt.Text) And (Integer.Parse(txt.Text) >= 1 And Integer.Parse(txt.Text) <= 20) Then
                    correctValidation = True
                Else
                    correctValidation = False
                    MsgBox("Please ensure all numbers are between 1 and 20")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next

Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("General: Please ensure all numbers are between 1 and 20")
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: This code works for me.  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `Integer.TryParse` and then `>= 1 AndAlso <= 20`. You could use this LINQ query:

```
Dim number As Int32
Dim invalidTextBoxes = 
    From txt In gbTechnical.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
    Where Not Integer.TryParse(txt.Text, number) OrElse number < 1 OrElse number > 20
Dim correctValidation = Not invalidTextBoxes.Any()
```

Note that you should almost always use `AndAlso` instead of `And` and `OrElse` instead of `Or` since those operators are Is short-circuiting boolean operators. This can be more efficient and - more important - can prevent errors. Consider this:

```
Dim text = ""
If txt IsNot Nothing And txt.Text.Length <> 0 Then text = txt.Text
```

This fails if `txt` is nothing since the second condition is evaluated even if the first already was evaluated to `false` which causes a `NullReferenceException` at `txt.Text`.

Comment: Thank you, that appears to work- would I replace my correctValidation boolean with your valid one?

Comment: @Nick: yes. I could rename it to `correctValidation` if it helps. **Edit** done. Note that my approach also enables to output which textboxes contained incorrect numbers or invalid formats. Therefore you just need to use `"Invalid: " & String.Join(", ", invalidTextBoxes.Select(Function(txt) txt.Text)))`.

Comment: Okay, just checking- thank you very much for your advice

Answer (score 0):

if you only want a number value, why don't you try to use NumericUpDown. You can also set the Minimum and Maximum in property or use

```
NumericUpDown1.Maximum = 20
```

so, there won't be a need to do checkNumbers.

Or is there any reason that you have to use textbox??